# Attach to a process on the Android device

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, android-debug, flutter-debug

I've published an Android bundle on Play Store for internal testing. Now I've installed it (from Play Store) on a physical device and started. As the application is malfunctioning I want to see the logs as I did by starting debugging right from VS Code (or Android Studio for what it's worth). But I see no such possibility. I've uploaded debug symbols to the release but it didn't change anything.

On VS Code I see following options:

[image]

None of those works.

On Android Studio I tried to attach debugger to a running process (the application is running at the moment) and see no available processes on the Samsung device:
[image]

I just need to see logs, I don't need a step-by-step debugger.

So the question is: is it possible to attach a debugger to an application installed from Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for my needs I found a solution. Android Studio's Logcat shows all logs from the connected device. There I can filter out `flutter` tagged entries and see my application.

Only thing that puzzles me is the filtering by the package name. Each entry I see shows my package name. But if I click on it and choose `Add "package:com.myapp" to Filter` no entries are shown anymore. But I can live with that.

Another option is running `adb logcat` on my device. That's even better one